# is my answer of time complexity is correct , if yes then why?

Tags: time-complexity

Time Complexity:

If the number of primary operations of an algorithm that takes an array of size n as input are `3n^2 + 5n`. The worst case time complexity of the algorithm will be?

The answer of this will be `O(N^2)`
if yes then why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the answer is `O(N^2)`.

The purpose of the Big-O notation is to find what is the dominant factor in the asymptotic behavior of a function as the value tends towards the infinity.

In other words, the intuition behind removing the coefficient `(K*f(x) = O(f(x)))` lies in what we try to measure with computational complexity.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation for more information